# php fetching page using http post

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I have to fetch exam results from the page http://cbseresults.nic.in/class1211/cbse122012.htm
Sampleroll number is 4623447.
They are using http post to post the form data.I wrote the following code to post data.But it is not providing the needed results.I am posting the needed cookies and post variables.But still I am not getting the output.What change should I make for send_post function,so that it will be working.Here is my code

```
echo cbse12_data_extractor(4623447);
function cbse12_data_extractor($regNo) {
    $source_url = 'http://cbseresults.nic.in/class1211/cbse122012.asp';
    $post_vars = array('regno'=>$regNo);
    $cookies = array('_tb_pingSent'=>1);
   // $extraHeaders = array('Host'=>'http://cbseresults.nic.in');
    return send_post($source_url,$post_vars,$cookies);
}

function send_post( $url, $data ,$cookies='',$extraHeaders = '') //sends data     array(param=>val,...) to the page $url in post method and returns the reply string
{
    $post    = http_build_query( $data );
    $header =  "Accept-language: en\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 
            "Content-Length: " . strlen( $post ) . 
            "\r\nUser-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n";

    if($extraHeaders) {
        foreach($extraHeaders as  $headerN  => $val) {
            $header = $header.$headerN.': '.$val."\r\n";
        }

    } 
    if($cookies) {
        $cookieArr = array();
        foreach($cookies as  $cookie  => $value) {
            array_push($cookieArr,$cookie.'='.$value);
        }
        $cookieStr = "Cookie: ".implode('; ',$cookieArr)."\r\n";
        $header = $header.$cookieStr;
    }
    $context = stream_context_create( array(
         "http" => array(
             "method" => "POST",
            "header" => $header,
            "content" => $post 
        ) 
    ) );
    //echo $header;
    $page    = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
    return $page;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can' send `POST` data using `file_get_contents`. Use `CURL` for this task

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,your_parameters);       
// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: What about stream_context_create

Comment: You can send POST request with `file_get_contents()`, plus it seems that you're missing the cookie jar part here.

Comment: cookie jar part. Can  you explain it?